# Contacts from Google not downloading to MBP

Tags: macos, mac, google-sync

Never had a problem before. Enabled my Google account on a new MBP yesterday, and asked to sync contacts. A day later, none of them have populated. Am I overlooking something? Any way to force a manual download (other than export/import, since that would defeat the purpose)?

EDIT: I went and disabled/re-enabled the account a few more times and it worked.

Comment: Does the side-bar show Google? https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VwmQ.png

Comment: Thanks. That made me look at the groups and it now works. It’s a mystery why it sometimes takes ten tries and sometimes works right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable and Re-enable the account can work in Contacts app preferences.